# Struts 2 HTMLissue when using <s:doubleselect>

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2

I am using `<s:doubleselect>` in my jsp. The problem is both come on different row while I want the in same line. Here is the code

```
      <s:doubleselect theme="css_xhtml"  labelposition="top" 
     requiredposition="left" name="index" cssClass="dropdown_menu" list="#request.constants.keySet()" 
   doubleList="#request.constants[top]" doubleName="oldValue"
 doubleCssClass="dropdown_menu" ></s:doubleselect>
```

How it can be possible to put them on same line?

Comment: have you tried them with `simple` theme? and its better to see its generated HTML as what causing this problem?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I've tried with the theme `css_xhtml` but it didn't work.

Comment: there is difference the way HTML being generated when using `css_xhtml` theme and when using `simple` theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is an unfortunate holdover from the old UI tags.

The *easiest* solution is to use CSS to change `<br/>` styling inside the `.wwctrl` class (changes all controls, which may be what you want anyway):

```
.wwctrl br {
  display: none;
}
```

A less-practical, but potentially cleaner, solution would be to extend the theme and tweak the control's template. There are a number of controls that have some questionable HTML, but hardly anybody uses the specialized controls, so we never fix them.

Comment: Thanks Dave..   Where should I add this CSS, in my jsp itself? Sorry but I didn't understand the second solution.

Comment: @NIVESHSENGAR It doesn't matter where you put the CSS, although I'd put it wherever the rest of your CSS is. For details regarding extending the themes/templates see [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html) and [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html).